ArcGIS JS SDK querying features with geometry
I am querying a layer in ArcGIS map with ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript.
When I query a feature with geometry and without type a where clause into the query, the query does not return results.
If I query a feature with geometry and with typing a where clause which reduces the result set of the query, it works like expected, it selects correct features from layer.
If I query a feature with geometry and with typing a where clause which does not reduce the result set of the query(for ex where 1=1 condition), it does not work, does not select any featureset.
here is my code:
        const query = new Query();
        query.geometry = geometry;
        query.returnGeometry = true;
        query.units = 'meters';
        query.spatialRelationship = (geometry.type === 'point') ? 'intersects' : 'contains';
        query.outFields = ['*'];
        // query.where = "name like '%'";   -> not working
        // query.where = "name like 'L%'";  -> works as expected(note that all elements in the layer already starts with letter 'L')
        // query.where = "ESRI_OID > 0";    -> works for some
        // query.where = "1=1";             -> not working
        layer.queryFeatures(query).then(featureSet => { 
            // see the results
        });

Why my query is not working if I do not add a where clause which reduces the resultset?

What do you mean by reducing my question to one question?  I have one question about why my query is not working when I do not add a where clause to it. There is no multiple questions as you see.
And also dhanged my one question that is more understandable for everyone.

"When I query a feature with geometry and without type a where clause into the query, the query does not return results".  'When' in here is not a question phrase, it means 'if' in here. But if it is confusing for you I will change to 'if' phrase.

For me it works without problems with query.where = "state_name like '%'" and query.where = "1=1" on  feature layer url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/OverlaySchools/FeatureServer/0".

We realize that, if the geographical spatial reference is null in the database for even only one record, whole querying mechanism is corrupting. We analyzed all data and found a corrupted record with spatial reference null. After we fixed that, all the things became normal.

You can put that info into answer, it might help somebody with the same problem.

We realized that, if the geographical spatial reference is null in the database for even only one record, whole querying mechanism is corrupting. We analyzed all data and found a corrupted record with spatial reference null. After we fixed that, all the things became normal.
